# How do I reach 1M coins?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-2

So I finished the main game, completed every level, collected every star coin, I even

> finished the secret star world and collected every moon coin

Right now I have about 57K coins, it seems absurd to repeat this process 20 times to reach 1M coins... I know playing the game in coop yields more coins, but unfortunately I'm the only one I know who owns a 3DS and lives in my vicinity.

So how can I reach the 1M coin target? Do I repeat endlessly the rainbow levels? Is there some sort of glitch? Or am I missing some special game mode which yields unusual amount of coins?

Comment: You'd only have to complete the process 20 times given the numbers you gave -- I don't have the game, but either something is off with your reported numbers or with your math. 1M/57K = 17.5ish

Comment: An overlooked typo :P

Comment: Grind, because as Nintendo is well aware, perceived value from increased gametime might mitigate criticism towards the game. See NSMB DS being 100%'able in a few hours. Getting 1 million coins gets you basically nothing, just ignore it and play a better game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw this today, which is a video describing a trick whereby you can get 30,000 coins in 2 minutes by exploiting a well-placed turtle and vine in a hidden area above world 3-4.

It appears that there's some sort of cap at 30,000 coins, which prevents the total going over this.  You'd have to repeat this trick around 34 times in order to go from 0 to 1,000,000 coins, which would probably take about an hour and a half to two hours depending on how fast you can repeat the "glitch."